# GTX 970 Zotac and MSI SLI: "Maximize 3D performance" option unavailable in Nvidia Control Panel

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, sli

### Attempt to pair a couple of GTX 970's with SLI is failing. One is a Zotac, the other an MSI.

From what I can gather from the many many posts I've read online now, the cards SHOULD be compatible. I do see both of them in device manager, and the SLI option is shown in NVIDIA Control Panel - but I can't enable it.

The option is just grayed out like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/I6ayRVD.png]

It shows this warning below the options: "To use maximum 3D performance connect the SLI-ready graphics cards with an SLI connector." I AM using a brand new bendy bridge though.

**ATTEMPTS TO SOLVE INCLUDE:**

- Reseating cards / Bridges
- Switching card slots
- Using a different bridge (altho one of the bridges I had did not say SLI on
  it, so I don't know if it's actually for SLI)
- Updating mobo BIOS
- Uninstalling & cleaning drivers and reinstalling them
- Looked for SLI settings in BOIS (there are none as far as I can tell)
- Switching to single monitor
- Using either top or bottom card for monitor output

**I HAVE NOT YET TRIED:**

- Another SLI 2-way bridge (I will once I can get my hands on one)
- 3rd party SLI software (not sure I want to do that)

**BUILD:**

- Windows 7 Ultimate
- GIGABYTE GA-Z97X-UD5H-BK - Black Edition
- ZOTAC GeForce GTX 970 - 4GB GDDR5
- MSI GeForce GTX 970 - 4GB GDDR5
- Intel Core i5-4690K Devils Canyon
- G.Skill RipjawsX DDR3-2133 C9 DC - 16GB
- XFX ProSeries XXX Edition - 850W PSU
- Samsung 840 EVO SSD - 250GB

Answer (score 0):

### Got it working!

It seems the cards were not compatible after all - at least not without som 3rd party help. I got them working together in SLI by downloading a small program called **DifferentSLIAuto** from this thread (V1.5 did it for me):

https://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/sli-with-different-cards.158907/

It's quite easy to install, but remember to follow ALL steps as instructed in the readme, **including the test mode step**. If you don't it won't work. Hope this helps someone!

Btw, V1.5 of DifferentSLIAuto was not on the GitHub page (only 1.0 - 1.4). For some unknown reason it was posted directly in the thread I mentioned - I don't remember which page, but it's there somewhere. Worked for me with Nvidia's 373.06 driver.